# how do I style a particular ELEMENTOR section using the native wordpress customize>additional css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

```css
.elementor-widget-image{
   display: none;
   }
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6806127 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="6806127" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
```

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6806127 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="6806127" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">
```

Other pages within this same elementor theme make use of this exact HTML code where I added a section.

When I style the intended page using the .elementor-widget-image, this style is applied to every other page that has a section like this.

I am trying to target the ID(ie. data-id"6806127") so that the styling affects only this page.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `data attribute` directly as CSS selector to style it

```
[data-id="6806127"] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

---

Working Example

```css
[data-id="6806127"] {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6806127 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="6806127" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="image.default">abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to

1. Assign the section, column OR the module a custom class by navigating to [Edit {Element Name} > Advanced > CSS Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OipJ.png)
2. Use Inspect Element to Identify the relevant class and tag that you will be targeting
3. Write the required CSS in [Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wX6d.png)

Alternatively, you can go with Elementor Pro and Write the CSS for each specific module in the "Advanced" tab

Answer (score 0):

If you want your css to affect only a 1 page, you can use the page id generated by wordpress. When you inspect element and go to body class you can see a class on the body like this .page-id-103. This ID is unique per page, you can use it as a first selector of your css example:

```html
body.page-id-100 .elementor-widget-image{
   display: none;
}
```